# Time machine "Delete all backups of <file>" option missing

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, monterey, apfs

Previously, when you right clicked a file in the Time Machine view, you had an option to delete it and all its backed up copies.

[image: A screenshot showing the menu item on some old macOS version. Mac OS X Leopard, by my guess.]

I'm using macOS Monterey, and that appears to no longer exist:

[image: A screenshot of the option being absent on macOS Monterey]

Was this feature removed?

Answer (score 6):

The ability to delete all backups of a file was removed when Time Machine changed to using destination disks formatted as APFS with Big Sur.

This loss of functionality is, in my view, more than compensated by the improved reliability of Time Machine to APFS.

For the [best in depth articles on Time Machine](https://eclecticlight.co/tag/time-machine/) see the ["Time Machine to APFS" on the Eclectic Light blog](https://eclecticlight.co/2017/10/29/last-week-on-my-mac-time-machine-and-apfs/)

Comment: I'm still using an HFS drive to back up via Time Machine, is there seriously no way to do this now? I have many gigabytes worth of homebrew that I'd like to delete.